# When the Auth Server redirects to the SSO Proxy server it doesn't know the login was successful

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

After successfully logging into the authentication server it redirects back the SSO-enabled proxy server but the proxy server doesn't recognize that the user authenticated, so it pops up the 3rd Party Permission page instead of forwarding the user to the originally requested protected resource. Once you click Accept on the third party permission page you are redirected to the originally requested protected resource.

1. GET http://localhost:8085/angular-example/ 302
   Response Header: Location: http://localhost:8085/angular-example/
   Response Header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=15F0789B7182469477E5F713D64A9BF3; Path=/; HttpOnly
2. GET http://localhost:8085/login 302 
   Request Cookie: JSESSIONID=15F0789B7182469477E5F713D64A9BF3
   Response Header: Location: http://localhost:8084/oauth/authorize?client_id=zuul-proxy-example&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8085/login&response_type=code&state=SdY74y
3. GET http://localhost:8084/oauth/authorize?client_id=zuul-proxy-example&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8085/login&response_type=code&state=SdY74y 302
   Request Header: Cookie: JSESSIONID=15F0789B7182469477E5F713D64A9BF3
   Response Header: Location: http://localhost:8084/login
   Response Header: Set-Cookie: SESSION=Zjk5Y2Y5YTEtMjE2OC00MTRkLThmNGUtNGZlODFkOTI4MWNj; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
4. GET http://localhost:8084/login 200 
   Request Header: Cookie: JSESSIONID=15F0789B7182469477E5F713D64A9BF3; SESSION=Zjk5Y2Y5YTEtMjE2OC00MTRkLThmNGUtNGZlODFkOTI4MWNj
5. GET http://localhost:8084/oauth/authorize?client_id=zuul-proxy-example&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8085/login&response_type=code&state=SdY74y 200
   Request Header: Cookie: JSESSIONID=15F0789B7182469477E5F713D64A9BF3; SESSION=MmVhODcyMmMtZDc0MS00Njk3LTk4MTktYTg4MmJhYjI4YmQ2
6. POST http://localhost:8084/oauth/authorize 
   Request Header: Cookie: JSESSIONID=15F0789B7182469477E5F713D64A9BF3; SESSION=MmVhODcyMmMtZDc0MS00Njk3LTk4MTktYTg4MmJhYjI4YmQ2
   Response Header: Location: http://localhost:8085/login?code=KjDZ7n&state=SdY74y
   Response Header: Set-Cookie: SESSION=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
7. GET http://localhost:8085/login?code=KjDZ7n&state=SdY74y 302
   Request Header: Cookie: JSESSIONID=15F0789B7182469477E5F713D64A9BF3
   Response Header: Location: http://localhost:8085/angular-example/
   Response Header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C201DF4673C6644D0B62F166481386C3; Path=/; HttpOnly
8. GET http://localhost:8085/angular-example/ 200

This is a Spring Boot 2.1.8.RELEASE Zuul Proxy server and a Spring Boot 2 Authentication Server configured as closely as possible to the working Spring Boot 1.5.x authentication server.

### Setup

1. Clone https://github.com/smitchell/spring-security-5-upgrade_sso-auth-server
2. mvn spring-boot:run
3. Clone https://github.com/smitchell/cloud-foundry-angular-example
4. mvn spring-boot:run
5. Clone https://github.com/smitchell/cloud-foundry-angular-example
6. ng serve  --baseHref=/angular-example/

### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Navigate to http://localhost:8085/angular-example/
2. Login as "user" / "password"
3. The third-party auth page appears. Click Agree.
4. The Angular home page is displayed.

## PROXY SERVER

```
proxy:
  permitAll:
    matches: /login,/*.js,/favicon.ico,*.map,/*.css,/robots.txt
zuul:
  add-proxy-headers: true
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  ignoredPatterns: /**/health/**,/**/mappings/**
  ignored-services: "*"
  routes:
    angular-example:
      path: /angular-example/**
      url: http://localhost:4200/angular-example/
    auth-service:
      path: /auth-example/**
      url: http://localhost:4202/auth-example
      sensitiveHeaders: Authorization
      stripPrefix: false
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8084/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8084/oauth/authorize
      clientId: zuul-proxy-example
      clientSecret: ####
server:
  port: 8085
```

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*.css","/*.js","/favicon.ico","/*.map","/robots.txt")
            .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8085/angular-example/")
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable();
    // @formatter:on
  }
```

## AUTH SERVER CONFIGURATION

```
server:
  port: 8084
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    open-in-view: false
```

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/",  "/oauth", "/login",  "/api/authenticate", "/oauth/authorize")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage( "/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(privateKey, authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(privateKey, authenticationManager()));
    // @formatter:on
  }
```

Bottom line, I want to understand why the authentication is not returning the same state parameter, which is preventing the proxy server from knowing the previous redirect to the authentication server was successful.

Here is a single sign-on from our Spring Security 4 authentication server which is working:

1. GET https://test.[hostname].com/[context path]/ 302
   Response Header: Location: http://test.[hostname].com/login
   Response Header: server: cloudflare
   Response Header: set-cookie: __cfduid=dd164391fe59500752e3500ab3de6a23c1569423515; expires=Thu, 24-Sep-20 14:58:35 GMT; path=/; domain=.[hostname].com; HttpOnly; Secure
2. GET http://test.[hostname].com/login 301
   Request Header: Cookie: JSESSIONID=C0C62552AAE5F7E8A420EEDD1869AA2A; **VCAP_ID**=b87f667f-ec72-4a1d-6265-5979
   Response Header: Location: https://test.[hostname].com/login
   Response Header: Server: cloudflare
3. GET https://test.[hostname].com/login 302 
   Request Header: Cookie: **cfduid=dd164391fe59500752e3500ab3de6a23c1569423515; JSESSIONID=C0C62552AAE5F7E8A420EEDD1869AA2A; __VCAP_ID**=b87f667f-ec72-4a1d-6265-5979
   Response Header: location: https://auth-service-test-[hostname].cfapps.io/oauth/authorize?client_id=proxy-service&redirect_uri=http://test.[hostname].com/login&response_type=code&state=N2mPnD
4. GET https://auth-service-test-[hostname].cfapps.io/oauth/authorize?client_id=proxy-service&redirect_uri=http://test.[hostname].com/login&response_type=code&state=N2mPnD 302 
   Response Header: Location: https://auth-service-test-[hostname].cfapps.io/login
   Response Header: Set-Cookie: SESSION=4d4be900-b461-4a57-b18b-c5e073e04b25; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
5. GET https://auth-service-test-[hostname].cfapps.io/login
   Request Header: Cookie: SESSION=4d4be900-b461-4a57-b18b-c5e073e04b25
6. POST https://auth-service-test-[hostname].cfapps.io/login 200
   Request Header: Cookie: SESSION=4d4be900-b461-4a57-b18b-c5e073e04b25
   Response Header: Location: https://auth-service-test-[hostname].cfapps.io/oauth/authorize?client_id=proxy-service&redirect_uri=http://test.[hostname].com/login&response_type=code&state=N2mPnD
   Response Header: Set-Cookie: SESSION=661f73be-a34a-4d3a-83d7-c8a8c682d392; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
7. GET https://auth-service-test-[hostname].cfapps.io/oauth/authorize?client_id=proxy-service&redirect_uri=http://test.[hostname].com/login&response_type=code&state=N2mPnD 302 
   Request Header: Cookie: SESSION=661f73be-a34a-4d3a-83d7-c8a8c682d392
   Response Header: Location: http://test.[hostname].com/login?code=o8S3fA&state=N2mPnD
   Response Header: Set-Cookie: SESSION=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
8. GET http://test.[hostname].com/login?code=o8S3fA&state=N2mPnD 301 
   Request Header: Cookie: JSESSIONID=C0C62552AAE5F7E8A420EEDD1869AA2A; **VCAP_ID**=b87f667f-ec72-4a1d-6265-5979
   Response Header: Location: https://test.[hostname].com/login?code=o8S3fA&state=N2mPnD
9. GET https://test.[hostname].com/login?code=o8S3fA&state=N2mPnD 302 
   Request Header: cookie: **cfduid=dd164391fe59500752e3500ab3de6a23c1569423515; JSESSIONID=C0C62552AAE5F7E8A420EEDD1869AA2A; __VCAP_ID**=b87f667f-ec72-4a1d-6265-5979
   Response Header: set-cookie: JSESSIONID=8B0E676E8BFE337A598BE060EEA76126; Path=/; HttpOnly
   Response Header: set-cookie: **VCAP_ID**=b87f667f-ec72-4a1d-6265-5979; Path=/; HttpOnly
10. GET https://test.[hostname].com/[context path]/ 200

Answer (score 0):

The fix can be made in the proxy:

```
auto-approve-scopes: '.*' # <-- Not for production.
```

-- OR --
Change the proxy service client in the auth service:

```
clientDetails.setAutoApproveCsv("true");
```